# LimeJS director.makeMobileWebAppCapable(); makes screen blank

Tags: web-applications, screen, limejs

In my helloWorld template from `LimeJS` I get a blank screen with FPS box running and nothing else.

However if I just comment out `director.makeMobileWebAppCapable();` it runs just fine. I can see the orange circle and move it around. Spent 2 days on google and formus and couldnt find anyone else having this same problem, in all tutorials nobody even mention this line so I guess everyone assumes it always works.

I had no troubles installing `LimeJS` I dont get any other errors, with `director.makeMobileWebAppCapable();` commented out I was able to go through a few tutorials and everything works fine but this one function.

I use:

> ```
> win xp sp3, 
> python 2.7.3
> ```

Got all the other esensials mentioned on the getting started page. Has anyone any idea what might be causing this ?

Answer (score 1):

Run it in Chrome or something with a debugger and look at the console. I run mine in chrome, right click and "inspect element" opens up my debugger frame, then I just click "console" tab and see if any errors are being thrown.

Comment: I'm assuming this is after you've declared your director as well. :)